# Como alterar tamanho padrão de um ícone?

Tags: java, javafx, icons

Existe alguma maneira de alterar o tamanho padrão de um ícone de uma aplicação javaFX?

Eu tenho uma imagem que pretendo usar como ícone da aplicação, mas ela acaba por ficar pequena demais tanto no canto superior esquerdo da janela quanto na barra Tarefas.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: O que já tentou fazer? Edite a pergunta e adicione sua tentativa ou onde você quer fazer isso.

Comment: Isso tem a ver com o tamanho da imagem do seu ícone, o SO reduz de acordo com o local onde será exibido. Mesmo seu ícone sendo 128x128 na barra de tarefas ele aparecerá 32x32 por exemplo.

Comment: Sim, mas não há maneira de alterar este padrão? Nem tanto na barra de tarefas, eu precisaria mais disso na própria janela criada utilizando javafx.

Comment: Acredito que não, inclusive tem até alguns bugs no JDK onde pessoas reclamam da qualidade dos ícones que o JDK 8 coloca. Isso foi maracado para correção no java 9. Você conhece alguma aplicação que tenha um ícone grande?

Comment: Não. O problema é que esse ícone acabou ficando pequeno por causa dos traços, por isso tentei procurar se havia alguma maneira de aumentar o tamanho um pouco. Acho que vai ficar assim mesmo então. Obrigado!